# Slow uploads to bigQuery using golang client

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am using deprecated BigQuery Golang library.
Lately uploads became much slower. I wonder if updating the client to a new library will make a performance improvement. I couldn't find in the documentation anything saying about performance improvement.

Old deprecated library I am currently using:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/tree/main/bigquery/v2

New client:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/tree/main/bigquery

Should I expect to get performance improvement with the new library?

Answer (score 1):

The `cloud.google.com/go/bigquery` package uses the `google-api-go-client` bigquery package under the hood.  I wouldn't expect an improvement in raw network throughput from the switch, but you might see improvements due to how the cloud package does more of the low level API management for you.

To really answer the question, you'd need to be able to detail what you're doing and try to quantify the details a bit more: are you sending bytes to GCS, and then constructing a load job?  Sending an inline upload as a load job?  Streaming data?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/v0.65.0/bigquery/v2/bigquery-gen.go#L9865 I am using this API to upload files sizes of up to 100MB in chunks of 5MB ....Jobs.Insert(c.Settings.GCloudProject, req).Media(obj.Body, googleapi.ChunkSize(chunkSize)).Context(ctx).Do()

Comment: Inline media upload, then.  I'm not aware of library changes of impact here.  You could try comparing local timing to when the bigquery load job is created; it will at least tell you the latency split between the media upload and the load job processing on the bigquery side.

Comment: I added logs, and the PrepareUpload phase is taking way longer then expected, any suggestions how to make that phase faster?

Comment: That seems likely to be a local filesystem concern.  That's a method for ascertaining if chunking is even necessary.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting to change .Media(f, googleapi.ChunkSize(chunkSize)) to Media(f) and that might reduce the long proccessing time? Looking at the code, it will use 16MB chunk size, instead of the 5MB I currently using. Or that I should use the size of the file I am trying to upload to avoid chunking all together

Comment: It's not clear what the right answer here might be, but it doesn't seem to be related to your original inquiry which was about whether the library itself got slower.

Comment: I also noticed there is the option of streaming the data, rather then using load jobs, using .InsertAll(...) wondering if that should be the why to go here